# Html contents not rendering using Angular selector

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an angular 2/4 app and having trouble rendering the app.component.html in the main index.cshtml page. However I can see only the word loading that is hardcoded in the index.cshtml page. Is there any issue with my template url path or am i missing something. I have checked the developer tools and can't see any error

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core'


@Component({

    selector: 'mrdb-app',
    templateUrl : './app.component.html'

})


export class AppComponent {

    pageTitle: string = "Movies Review Database";

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>Angular 2 : Getting Started</h1>>
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**systemjs.cofig.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({        
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': '/libs/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: '/Scripts',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js',
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<mrdb-app>Loading...</mrdb-app>
```

Comment: How does your `index.cshtml` look like?

Comment: yes. updated the post

Comment: Unable to put the debugger. I can't see the main.js in the source tab of the developer toos

Comment: Not sure the problem is as i cant see any error

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `module.id` in order to use relative paths in your component just like this:

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'mrdb-app',
templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

or much better use the `systemjs-angular-loader.js` and use relative paths without the `modueId` at all.

Comment: could you share how the systemjs-angular-loader.js looks like

Comment: I added systemjs-angular-loader.js  but no difference

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. The problem was I was trying to call App.Module.js directly instead of calling main.js in my layout.cshtml page. The main.js is responsible for bootstrapping the app.module and starting the load.